# Button on top of all activity android

Tags: android

I need to create button on top of all activity in android,what i want to do is need to create a button which should be located on top of all activities,one button common for all activities,help me in solving this?

Comment: Use `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: Use ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock Library.

Comment: If its just a native button you wish to use, then try using fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Use following library to use actionbar
[ActionBarSherlock Library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

or if your min sdk version is >11 then you can use Actionbar [Actionbar Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class (say Base.java) which extends Activity. Put all the buttons in this class.

Make every other class extend Base.java and inflate ui as

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.footer); // ui of Base.java
    ViewGroup.inflate(this, R.layout.current_layout, vg);
```

If all you want is common button for all activities then this is much simpler solution, but if you want more things then ActionBarSherlock is great choice.